# \printbibliography writing ".bib" at bottom of bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber

I seem to be getting a weird error in my thesis' bibliography. All entries are looking as they are supposed to, but for some reason after the last entry latex writes the line "references.bib" (which obviously is the name of my .bib file).

For the bibliography-related parts of the preamble I only got the follwing lines:

```
% ...
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\begin{document}

% chapters here
\printbibliography{references.bib}
\end{document}
```

My only problem is that "references.bib" line, how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Welcome, get rid of the liine `\bibliography{references.bib`} and get rid of the curly braces and its content for `\printbibliography`

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I'm marking musicman's answer as correct one, because your two posts are basically indentical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}

% chapters here
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With biblatex you don't need `\bibliography{..}`, and `\printbibliography` only takes optional parameters, I think. Check manual.

Comment: Or rather `\addbibresource` is the replacement for `\bibliography`. The main difference being that `\addbibresource` needs the file extension `.bib` and `\bibliography` doesn't. Plus some of the fancy features like file access from remote sources require `\addbibresource`.